# GAS getSharingAccess() restriction scopes

Tags: google-apps-script

**Question**
Is there any way to restrict the scope [drive.readonly] to only apply to current sheet?
I need to call getSharingAccess(), only on current sheet.

**Background**
We have built a public google addon thats calling our API with a customer uniqe API-Key.
To check that the sheet is not shared with others (must be private to user), we check if Sheet is shared.
If sheet is shared we give a warning to user.

```
var docId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 
var access  = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getSharingAccess();
```

**Problem**
The scope **drive.readonly** is giving full read access to all files on users drive.
We only need to check current sheet if this is shared.
We dont need access to all files on users drive.
Many users are afraid to give this full access to any addon.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingaccess

Thanks,
Br,
Henrik

Comment: If the spreadsheet is shared as `DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE`, you could probably use `const numUsers = ss.getViewers().concat(ss.getEditors()).length;` requiring only the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly` scope, but that will not help if the file is shared as `DriveApp.Access.ANYONE` or `DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN`.

Comment: Thanks. Good point.
The user can share sheet with friends or make the sheet Public to all. None is allowed. I need to check both cases. So this does not help, I think?

Comment: Considering that methods for managing access for specific users (e.g. `getEditors()`, `addViewer(user)`, I'd suggest filing a feature request in Issue Tracker for adding methods to manage other types of access (e.g. `DOMAIN`, `ANYONE`), using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

There's no way to get information of which types of [Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) (`anyone`, `domain`, etc.) are associated with current spreadsheet while using a scope that is restricted to this file.

#### Explanation:

Using scope `spreadsheets.currentonly`, you can know whether the file has been shared with specific users (eg. [Spreadsheet.getViewers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getviewers)), but not if it has been shared with all users in a domain, or made public.

In order to get this information, you would at least need the scope `drive.metadata.readonly`, which is a restricted scope, the same as `drive.readonly` (see [scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing)).

`drive.file` cannot be used for that, since it only gives access to files created or opened by your project, and this doesn't seem to include container files for your bound script.

The easiest way to retrieve this information via `drive.metadata.readonly` (the more restricted scope you can use) is by doing the following:

- Enable [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).
- [Set the following explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in your manifest file (necessary to set a less permissive scope; otherwise Apps Script would automatically set `drive.readonly` or `drive`):

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
  ]
```

- Copy and run the following function to list the types of permission associated with this file:

```
function getCurrentFilePermissions() {
  const ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const permissions = Drive.Permissions.list(ssid);
  const permissionTypes = permissions["items"].map(permission => permission["type"]);
  console.log(permissionTypes);
  return permissionTypes;
}
```

#### Notes:

- [DriveApp.getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) requires `drive` or `drive.readonly`, `metadata` scopes cannot be used for that. That's why the Advanced Service is used.
- Considering that methods for managing access for specific users (e.g. `getEditors()`, `addViewer(user)`, I'd suggest filing a feature request in Issue Tracker for adding methods to manage other types of access (e.g. DOMAIN, ANYONE), using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Comment: Perfect. This works and tells if shared by user or Access like DOMAIN or ANYONE. I need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly" scope.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) has a [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method that lets you retrieve a [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files). The Files resource has a `shared` property that apparently indicates whether the file is shared or private to the owner.

It seems to be possible to specify the [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) scope or the [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) scope when sending a `get` request.

You can try the endpoint with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) panel — enter a spreadsheet ID in the `fileId` box, `shared` in the `fields` box, and untick the `Google OAuth 2.0` checkbox. The spreadsheet must be readable by the world for this test to work.

Another test to try against the `get` endpoint:

`const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint + '?' + parameters, { headers : { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }});`

It may also be worth trying `DriveApp` and the `Advanced Drive Service` and the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope.

As said, I have not tried any of the above, and you will have to do your own research to find if there is a solution there. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but get access error. Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingaccess

Comment: Edited the answer to add another possible approach. Cannot help you with the exception you mention without seeing your code.

Comment: This is Drive API, not Sheets API v3. Also `drive.file` cannot be used for this. At least `drive.metadata.readonly` has to be used.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. I can check the 'Shared' property to see if sheet is shared. I need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".

Comment: function isSharedByFileRequest()
{
  var fileid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 
  var endpoint= "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+fileid+"?fields=shared";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, { headers : { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }});
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  var isShared = data.shared;
  return isShared;
}